# How can I uniquely map a long string identifier to a numerical value in a single query (for bandwidth reasons)?

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have a Postgresql database (technically Greenplum) with data on individuals over time. The database has three fields: `user_id`, `monthly_date`, and `account_value`. When I put in a query, I have to download the results from a remote server, so bandwidth is an issue. Since the `user_id` field is a very long string (around 50 characters), I'd like to return a numerical value that corresponds 1:1 with each value of `user_id`, since this will take up less space.

For example, the database might have sample data like this:

```
63a9364385350b13473279    Jan-2000
63a9364385350b13473279    Feb-2000
2066937e2887w206010393    Apr-2001
036686037e507d01764237    Mar-2003
036686037e507d01764237    Jun-2003
036686037e507d01764237    Jul-2003
036686037e507d01764237    Dec-2003
90829x098327549n286418    Apr-2004
90829x098327549n286418    Sep-2004
67518x834512306933u500    Nov-2000
```

and I'm trying to work out a query using `ROW_NUMBER()` and various window functions like `PARTITION BY` to get results like this:

```
1    Jan-2000
1    Feb-2000
2    Apr-2001
3    Mar-2003
3    Jun-2003
3    Jul-2003
3    Dec-2003
4    Apr-2004
4    Sep-2004
5    Nov-2000
```

I know these aren't actual database formats, but I'm just using them as example data. Is this possible? I don't care (although it would be nice and very neat to see) if, for example, `63a9364385350b13473279` maps to `1` in one query and `2` in the next, but in any given query, `63a9364385350b13473279` should always map to the same value regardless of date. The mapped numbers don't need to be in sequence or have any meaningful value besides being unique.

Comment: Have you looked at using gp's `serial` type to have an auto-generated integer key for your users?

Comment: @jmelesky I don't control the schema at all. The datasets are purchased as-is from a third-party provider and uploaded to a data warehouse in another location, and when I want data from the database, I can put in one, and only one, query into a web form. When it completes, I get emailed a link to the download. Unfortunately, that's how my company's system works and I can't change it.

Comment: @jmelesky So to be clear, even my company's database admins don't really control the schema in that sense. The third-party data provider sells us the data in this format, and we can either take it or leave it (and unfortunately, we can't leave it because they're the only provider who sells these data).

Comment: Is it important that those numbers are a sequence or do you only need different numbers ?

Comment: @ClémentPrévost Just different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a unique number, this will do the trick:

```
SELECT
        id,
        split_part(t.d, '-', 2),
        row_number() OVER all_window - row_number() OVER group_window AS a_unique_number_by_id
FROM (
VALUES
        ('63a9364385350b13473279','Jan-2000'),
        ('63a9364385350b13473279','Feb-2000'),
        ('2066937e2887w206010393','Apr-2001'),
        ('036686037e507d01764237','Mar-2003'),
        ('036686037e507d01764237','Jun-2003'),
        ('036686037e507d01764237','Jul-2003'),
        ('036686037e507d01764237','Dec-2003'),
        ('90829x098327549n286418','Apr-2004'),
        ('90829x098327549n286418','Sep-2004'),
        ('67518x834512306933u500','Nov-2000')
) as t(id, d)
WINDOW group_window AS (
        PARTITION BY id
        ORDER BY split_part(t.d, '-', 2)
), all_window AS (
        ORDER BY split_part(t.d, '-', 2)
);
```

Here is the result:

```
           id           | split_part | a_unique_number_by_id
------------------------+------------+-----------------------
 63a9364385350b13473279 | 2000       |                     0
 63a9364385350b13473279 | 2000       |                     0
 67518x834512306933u500 | 2000       |                     2
 2066937e2887w206010393 | 2001       |                     3
 036686037e507d01764237 | 2003       |                     4
 036686037e507d01764237 | 2003       |                     4
 036686037e507d01764237 | 2003       |                     4
 036686037e507d01764237 | 2003       |                     4
 90829x098327549n286418 | 2004       |                     8
 90829x098327549n286418 | 2004       |                     8
(10 rows)
```

You should re-order it with another column to keep the original ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for dense_rank().

```
create table sample_data
(userid varchar(50) not null,
 monthly_date date not null)
distributed by (userid);

insert into sample_data (userid, monthly_date) values 
('63a9364385350b13473279','2000-01-01'),
('63a9364385350b13473279','2000-02-01'),
('2066937e2887w206010393','2001-04-01'),
('036686037e507d01764237','2003-03-01'),
('036686037e507d01764237','2003-06-01'),
('036686037e507d01764237','2003-07-01'),
('036686037e507d01764237','2003-12-01'),
('90829x098327549n286418','2004-04-01'),
('90829x098327549n286418','2004-09-01'),
('67518x834512306933u500','2000-11-01');

select dense_rank() over(order by userid) as new_userid, userid, monthly_date 
from sample_data
order by 2;

 new_userid |         userid         | monthly_date 
------------+------------------------+--------------
      1     | 036686037e507d01764237 | 2003-06-01
      1     | 036686037e507d01764237 | 2003-07-01
      1     | 036686037e507d01764237 | 2003-12-01
      1     | 036686037e507d01764237 | 2003-03-01
      2     | 2066937e2887w206010393 | 2001-04-01
      3     | 63a9364385350b13473279 | 2000-02-01
      3     | 63a9364385350b13473279 | 2000-01-01
      4     | 67518x834512306933u500 | 2000-11-01
      5     | 90829x098327549n286418 | 2004-09-01
      5     | 90829x098327549n286418 | 2004-04-01
(10 rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below script

```
create table test_schema.source_data (id varchar(50), dt varchar(50));

insert into test_schema.source_data
values ('63a9364385350b13473279','Jan-2000'),
    ('63a9364385350b13473279','Feb-2000'),
    ('2066937e2887w206010393','Apr-2001'),
    ('036686037e507d01764237','Mar-2003'),
    ('036686037e507d01764237','Jun-2003'),
    ('036686037e507d01764237','Jul-2003'),
    ('036686037e507d01764237','Dec-2003'),
    ('90829x098327549n286418','Apr-2004'),
    ('90829x098327549n286418','Sep-2004'),
    ('67518x834512306933u500','Nov-2000');


create temporary table id_mapping
as 
select t1.id, row_number() over(order by t1.id) rownum
from (
SELECT distinct id
FROM test_schema.source_data
 ) t1;

select t1.id, t1.dt, t2.rownum
from
test_schema.source_data t1
join id_mapping t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
```

And here is the result

```
id                      dt          rownum
------------------------+------------+-----
036686037e507d01764237  Dec-2003    1
036686037e507d01764237  Jul-2003    1
036686037e507d01764237  Jun-2003    1
036686037e507d01764237  Mar-2003    1
2066937e2887w206010393  Apr-2001    2
63a9364385350b13473279  Feb-2000    3
63a9364385350b13473279  Jan-2000    3
67518x834512306933u500  Nov-2000    4
90829x098327549n286418  Sep-2004    5
90829x098327549n286418  Apr-2004    5
```

Comment: This is probably a decent way to do this, but unfortunately I can only put in one query at a time (not a script) and the interface doesn't remember tables between queries, so the `select` statement won't have access to the temporary table created in the previous statement.